How do we calculate the time constant of this circuit?
For the below circuit, C1 changes its voltage from  +5V to 0V , whereas C2 changes from 0V to +5V.
The time taken to reach 63% of total change ( usually ~RC) is around 636ms. But Iam not able to derive this value by any possible combinations of R and C. Is it just impossible to predict the time constant analytically in this case?


This circuit has two capacitors and three resistors.  Depending on how they are arranged the circuit might be second order so the usual first order T=RC wouldn't apply.  The first step would be to write a time domain differential equation (using KCL and KVL) describing the output voltage in terms of the input voltage, and then solve for the time at which your output rises to 63%.  It's certainly possible to construct an analytical solution, although I will not take time to explain how here.

Because of the series resistance \$R_1\$, the two capacitors are not in parallel when you turn the excitation off: set the input voltage to 0 V (replace the source by a short circuit) and you can see it.
By applying the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs, you can write the 2nd-order polynomial describing this circuit:

If you consider the low-\$Q\$ approximation, then the 2nd-order expression can be factored by the product of two poles: one dominates the low-frequency response while the second occurs in the higher portion of the spectrum. With the given components values, we can consider that the time-domain response is dominated by the first pole whose time constant is 640 ms.

Here we need to consider C1 and C2 are in parallel, since effectively both incur same change in voltage.
So Ceff= (0.22+0.1) uF= 0.32uF
Reff =2 Meg
RC = 0.64s

This is a second-order circuit with two poles and the two capacitors are not in parallel when you turn the excitation off. However, because the series resistance with $C_1$ is much smaller than the 2-MOhm series resistance for the parallel path, then the sum of the two time constants involving $C_1$ and $C_2$  is approximated by the sum of the two capacitors times 2 MOhms.
